# Fade one image into another.

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <img id='slideshow' src="1.jpg">
    <script>

    $("#slideshow").fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $("#slideshow").attr('src','2.jpg');
    });

   </script>
</body>
```

I am trying to make a jQuery script where 1.jpg fades out and 2.jpg fades in but I only see 1.jpg and it stays there

Comment: why not put one behind the other and fade that one is in front ?

Comment: Did you get any errors check your console. Works fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for however many images you add. As long as they have the class `slideshow`.
Also this allows you to crossfade images. See below for non-crossfade below.
See this [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MgPF4/)

```
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <img id='slideshow' src="1.jpg">
    <img id='slideshow' src="2.jpg">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".slideshow").hide();

            var item = 0;
            loop = setInterval(function() {
                if(item == $(".slideshow").size()) {
                    item = 0;
                }
                $(".slideshow").fadeOut(300);
                $(".slideshow").eq(item).fadeIn(300);
                item++;
            }, 3000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**Non-Crossfade**

```
$(".slideshow").fadeOut(300, function () {
    $(".slideshow").eq(item).fadeIn(300);
});
```

**UPDATE**
You can add the following css to get the images to display in the same space.

```
.slideshow { position:absolute; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your awesome code.  I copied and pasted your source into another separate HTML file but I only see 1.jpg and 2.jpg placed side by side with no action at all.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user979431 see the update to the answer and check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MgPF4/

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$( "#slideshow" ).fadeOut( "slow", function( )  {
    $( "#slideshow" ).prop('src','2.jpg').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yLGRE/)**

This will fade out the original image, and once the fade has completed, change the image's src property, then begin to fade in the new image.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, In my answer I used a loop to continue to fade through as I guessed the op wanted a slideshow :P

Answer (score 0):

According to what you are saying .. If I understand you correctly ...  Although I may be mistaken, it seems like you are asking 1 to fade out .. change to 2 ... and fade 2 in??   If so, will this not work?

```
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<img id='slideshow' src="1.jpg">
<script>

$("#slideshow").fadeOut();
$("#slideshow").attr('src','2.jpg');
$("#slideshow").fadeIn();

</script>
</body>
```

That's the simple version, of course I would assume it will be put it inside a function on an `.on()` event or the like etc ...

Comment: No, that won't work as you described because the fadeIn will begin immediately after the fadeOut and src are changed instead of waiting.

Comment: You need to put the other two lines in the call back of the fadeout